# Lucene 8 Scoring

Tags: java, lucene

## I'm relatively new to Lucene 8 and wanted to understand how to migrate a legacy Solr 4 scoring to Lucene. This is how it is done currently with Solr 4.

```
  /*
         * From the SolrRelevancyFAQ:
         * How can I see the 0?
         * 
         * Request that the pseudo-field named "score" be returned by adding it
         * to the fl (field list) parameter. The "score" will then appear along
         * with the stored fields in returned documents. q=Justice League&fl=*,score
         */
```

## query.setFields( "*", "score" );

How do I do this with Lucene 8? I would rather keep it simple.
Is there a way to request a pseudo field returned like it's done above?
Thanks0

Answer (score 0):

## I ended up implementing the following solution:

searcher.search(query, request.getMaxResults(), new Sort(new SortField(request.getSortOrder().getFieldName(),

## SortField.Type.STRING, request.getSortOrder().isAscending() ? false : true)), true);

Note: The last argument, "doDocScores" is false by default. 
After doing this, ScoreDoc will contain the score of this document.